# Join two tables subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get `*` from the `users2` table where the user's location is within the given radius.

The location query works fine on the `user_location2` table.

```
SELECT uid, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(28.247800068217) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lon` ) - radians(-80.726205977101) ) 
+ sin( radians(28.247800068217) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM user_location2 
HAVING distance <= 25 ORDER BY time_stamp
```

and the inner join works fine without the location subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM users2
LEFT JOIN user_location2 
ON user_location2.uid = users2.id
```

I'm just having trouble combining the two. Here's my current query that just is returning all rows, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
SELECT *
FROM users2
LEFT JOIN user_location2 
     ON user_location2.uid = users2.id 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(26.247800068217) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lon` ) - radians(-89.726205977101) ) + sin( radians(26.247800068217) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM user_location2 
HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY time_stamp)
```

---

Edit included

I'm hoping to add in a 3rd table (user_like) to eliminate a lot of possible rows that shouldn't be included in the result.

Let's say the script is running for user_id = 88

[image: Here's a screenshot of the table state]

So basically users 89, 90 and 91 would fall under the location radius, but wouldn't be included in the result because user 88 already liked them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT users2.*
FROM users2
LEFT JOIN user_location2 
ON user_location2.uid = users2.id 
WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(28.247800068217) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lon` ) - radians(-80.726205977101) ) 
+ sin( radians(28.247800068217) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) )  < = 5
ORDER BY time_stamp
```

The join is fine between the two tables. The calculated column has been added in the select clause and the where clause because the filter requires it there. It would be easier to put that through a view so that if you need to change it, it can be done in one place.

EDIT: Removed the calculation from SELECT because I believe you don't need to see that. Just left it in the WHERE clause since it needs to be filtered on.

Comment: that's great! Seems to be working well. Is it possible to throw a few WHERE clauses from users2 on it? like WHERE users2.age > 25

Comment: Yes. Just add them before or after the condition and use AND or OR as needed.

Comment: Could you check my edited question when you get a chance? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Ask another question if you have more follow up questions.

Comment: @b_the_builder You can add in the query where uid1 = 88 and uid2 != 88.

Comment: I made a new question. Was getting some errors in my query when including columns from the user_like table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878098/add-3rd-table-to-left-join

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM users2 A
LEFT JOIN user_location2 B
   ON B.uid = A.id 
  WHERE  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(26.247800068217) ) * cos( radians(   `B.lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `B.lon` ) - radians(-89.726205977101) ) + sin( radians(26.247800068217) ) * sin( radians( `B.lat` ) ) ) ) > 25;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had some mixed results with this one. The query returned some wrong rows from the location radius.

Comment: It will be helpful if you show the correct and wrong result and You can put more condition to get the correct result.