# add 3rd table to left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query that fetches users within a certain distance of given point

```
SELECT users2.*
FROM users2
LEFT JOIN user_location2 
ON user_location2.uid = users2.id 
WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(28.547800068217) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lon` ) - radians(-82.726205977101) ) 
+ sin( radians(28.547800068217) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) )  <= 25
AND
ORDER BY time_stamp
```

I'm hoping to add in a 3rd table (user_like) to eliminate a lot of possible rows that shouldn't be included in the result.

Let's say the script is running for user_id = 88

[![Here's the state of the table][1]][1]

I'm having issues calling the third table or including it at all.

So basically users 89, 90 and 91 would fall under the location radius, but wouldn't be included in the result because user 88 already liked them.

Something like:

```
WHERE user_like.uid1 = 88 AND user_like.uid2 != (89,90,91)
```

Edit:

Here's the 3 table structures:

-users2

```
id int(11)
```

(other columns have been omitted because they are irrelevant in this case select *)

-user_location2

```
uid int(11)
lat double
lon double
time_stamp  bigint(20)
```

-user_like

```
uid1  int(11)
uid2  int(11)
time_stamp  bigint(20)
```

To clarify a bit more, I have a user sending up a request (let's say user 88) that should return all users within 25 miles of them (this part currently works). What I'm trying to add is the for the query to take into considering the user_like table. If user 88 already "liked" another user (uid1, uid2) then that should be removed from the query result because user 88 has already seen and liked that user.

Comment: I don't think that they results you are showing are from your query. What are the columns in your users2 table? What is the content of the user_like table? What defines if a user is like the other users?

Comment: the table I posted above is the 3rd table (user_like). The users2 table consists of a users ID, and basic info (name, age, gender) etc. I want to eliminate (for this instance) users 89, 90 and 91 from the results of the original query we worked on.

Comment: So in the result, you'd expect to see user 88 and to not see users 89, 90 and 91?

Comment: Learn to ask question properly.  Then probably someone will give you the right answer.  Where's your sample input, sample output.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @clinomaniac In this case I don't want any results. 88 is the user the script would be running for.

Comment: How useful is an image of a query? Answer: *As useful as images of data.*

Comment: Please. Please. Please. Read these [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Used_By_Already ok I've edited

Comment: Good start, thanks. There is a slight distinction between DDL and "sample data". When you debug any query, what do you do? (look at the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT users2.*
FROM users2
LEFT JOIN user_location2 
ON user_location2.uid = users2.id 
LEFT JOIN users_like ul ON ul.uid1 = users2.id
WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(28.547800068217) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lon` ) - radians(-82.726205977101) ) 
+ sin( radians(28.547800068217) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) )  <= 25
AND users2 != ul.uid2
ORDER BY time_stamp
```

Comment: Looks like that works! I'll have to run few more tests, but I got the results I was looking for.

Comment: ah I take that back. It doesn't return anything if I delete all rows in the user_like table. At that point it should return all of the users

Comment: I have changed the join. Try it now.

Comment: that's it! thank you so much, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not confident with this as I found the column names very confusing, and there is no sample data to inspect

```
SELECT users2.*
FROM users2
INNER JOIN user_location2 uloc ON users2.id <> uloc.uid
LEFT JOIN users_like ulike ON uloc.uid = ulike.uid1 and users2.id <> ulike.uid1 and users2.id <> uloc.uid2
WHERE users2.id = 88
AND (3959 * acos(cos(radians(28.547800068217)) 
            * cos(radians(uloc.lat)) 
            * cos(radians(uloc.lon) 
            - radians(- 82.726205977101)) 
            + sin(radians(28.547800068217)) 
            * sin(radians(uloc.lat)))) <= 25 
ORDER BY uloc.time_stamp 
## always reference with table aliases
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I just updated my answer with the table structures, so maybe that can help with some confusion.

Comment: also time_stamp is coming from the user_location2 table